# How to check what's kind of an iOS Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, templates

I am new on iOS programming. I download some samples from apple website.
How do I know what's kind of the sample? View-Based, Window-based, Navigation-based etc.

Comment: who down vote, please type your reason. If you know the answer, feel free to speak out.

Comment: Those are just goofy "quick-start" templates which all build on top of the same thing. (I wasn't the down vote)

Comment: I do not understand the reason for downvote.So +1.

Comment: @Steve, you mean apple developers are not using the templates which they provide us ?

Comment: @heefan, I posted an answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what @Steve said ( I was editing answer for some time now ... you put it better than I had :)), template does not create any indicator that allows you to find what kind of project. Of course the SDK setting and the run setting can help you understand if its for Iphone or MAC.

But if your project is created with some standard template, it is possible to understand which of those template was used.

Navigate to the .xcodeproj file for the corresponding project. CMD + click ( or right click) and choose open package contents. Open the .pbxproj file. By default this will open in Xcode, search for the term "Template". This will probably point you to the right direction.

Comment: HA... I just learned something. Nifty... but, honestly, I'm pretty surprised they keep that info around. If I had to guess it's more useful for things that really are different types of projects. Having that info for these templates is probably just a byproduct of having it in there for other reasons.

Comment: @doc_180, that's very useful information. From .pbxproj file I got the answer. thanks

Comment: @steve, I agree. It most probably has other reason to exist. you can create custom templates from your project. In that case, the template properties are inherited. That is one reason, but may be there are other.

Answer (score 0):

Your question "[...] what's kind of an iOS Application? [...] View-Based, Window-based, Navigation-based etc." **implies that these templates which ship with Xcode create fundamentally different "kinds" of applications**.

This is not true.

All of those project templates create the same kind of project.

They are simply there as a quick-start convenience.

Comment: agree, and that's why I am asking here. So if I wanna repeat apple's sample, I'd better start from empty project, right?

Comment: If you post an example (link) of a sample you're trying to use, I could probably help you.

Comment: actually that's lots. Suppose this sample, TapToZoom from official website, you can google it, quite easy to find it, or I can provide the link. Just from its code, i can customize from view-based, navigation-based and window-based application, but I wanna know what's the start point from the author.

Comment: I just downloaded that sample to see what you are talking about - but it comes with a complete Xcode project already... you don't have to create a new project at all to try it out. The point of those samples is usually to help you understand a particular concept - and that concept is orthogonal to the rest of the issues (like creating views, etc) in the sample.

Comment: yes, I just wanna try by myself ;-), but from the beginning, I was confused... anyway, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

View-based, Window-based, ... are actually the names given to project templates in Xcode. When choosing one at project creation, Xcode provides the stuff you will need, which includes subclasses of common controller classes.

In almost all cases, an iOS app will show a window, and a view inside, so you can consider facing a window-based or a view-based app every time.

About the others, have a look to the files Xcode put in the project folder, you should find a `UINavigationController` when working with a navigation-based app, and for example a `UITabBarController` when you develop a tab-based app.

Finally, the best answer you will find is actually in the excellent [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) provided by Apple.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot. I read the document many times, and tried some samples before, and then confused, apple provides the so-called quick start templates, but never follow it. Never mind, maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter of course, just think of Xcode templates as a way to get an app ready fast.